# Высокая нагрузка Drupal 7 на IIS

Tags: highload, sql-server, php, memcached, iis

Доброго времени суток.

Есть такой стек технологий: Drupal 7 (PHP) + IIS 7 + SQLServer. Настроено кэширование Memcache, и в добавок стоит модуль entity_cache. Нагрузочные тесты через locust показывают далеко не лучшие результаты. Открытие пары страниц при 500 пользователях - и система стабильно выдает 500 status_code. Пробовал wincache - до определенного момента держит лучше, но при некоторой нагрузке просто валится php_wincache.dll, и тогда резко все ответы - 500.

Может, кто посоветует, в какую сторону копать, для увеличения порога максимальной нагрузки?

Comment: Вначале нужно определить, кто тормозит - база данных, сервер IIS, сеть или ещё кто то.

Думаю, самый простой способ проверить базу - заглянуть в ее логи/админ утилиты.

Второе, что нужно проверить - а будет ли у Вас по факту 500 одновременных пользователей? может проблема надуманная? Тестилось ли на реальных пользователях?

Comment: Мне нужно расчитывать даже на бОльшую нагрузку...

Comment: 500тый статус ответа это = internal server error. тут бы в логи бэкенда смотреть нужною

Answer (score 1):

Копайте в сторону Linux в связке Nginx+PHP+MySQL+Memcache. Уверен что тот же сервер позволит выдержать бОльшее кол-во пользователей.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?